# insert input fied array in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to insert to DB with array input. but have an error. Please help me
this is my code:

1. in  view
    
                 
                   
                       Số công văn

   ```
                  <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="exampleInputpwd1">Người phê duyệt</label>
                   <div class="input-group">
                     <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i></div>                        
                     <select class="form-control" name="txtleader[]">
                     <?php 
                       $list_ld = DB::table('leaders')->select('id','Name')->get();
                     ?>
                     @foreach($list_ld as $item_ld)
                       <option value="{!! $item_ld->id !!}">{!! $item_ld->Name !!}</option>
                     @endforeach                              
                     </select>
                   </div>
                 </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Lí do xin vé</label>
                   <div class="input-group">
                     <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-question"></i></i></div>                        
                     <select class="form-control" name="txtlido[]">
                     <?php 
                       $list_rs = DB::table('reasons')->select('id','Name')->get();
                     ?>
                     @foreach($list_rs as $item_rs)
                       <option value="{!! $item_rs->id !!}">{!! $item_rs->Name !!}</option>
                     @endforeach 

                     </select>
                   </div>
                 </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="exampleInputpwd2">Công ty</label>
                   <div class="input-group">
                     <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-bank"></i></div>                        
                     <select class="form-control" name="txtCom[]">
                     <?php 
                       $list_c = DB::table('companies')->select('id','NameCOM')->get();
                     ?>
                     @foreach($list_c as $item_c)
                       <option value="{!! $item_c->id !!}">{!! $item_c->NameCOM !!}</option>
                     @endforeach 
                     </select>
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="exampleInputpwd2">Phòng</label>
                   <div class="input-group">
                     <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-building-o"></i></div>                        
                     <select class="form-control" name="txtRoom[]">
                     <?php 
                       $list_r = DB::table('rooms')->select('id','NameRO')->get();
                     ?>
                     @foreach($list_r as $item_r)
                       <option value="{!! $item_r->id !!}">{!! $item_r->NameRO !!}</option>
                     @endforeach 
                     </select>
                   </div>
                 </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="exampleInputpwd2">Giao cho</label>
                   <div class="input-group">
                     <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="ti-share"></i></div>                        
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputuname" placeholder="Chi nhánh/Đại diện nhận nhiệm vụ" name="txtReceiver[]">

                   </div>
                 </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                   <div class="checkbox checkbox-success"></div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="text-right"></div>           
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6">                
                 <div class="form-group nguoixin">
                   <label for="exampleInputuname">Người xin</label>
                   <div class="input-group">
                     <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>            
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputuname" placeholder="Người xin" name="txtnguoixin[]">                          
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputuname" placeholder="Người xin" name="txtnguoixin[]"> 
                     <div class="input-group-addon"><button class="add-more-nx"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button></div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="exampleInputuname">Mối quan hệ</label>
                   <div class="input-group">
                   <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="ti-exchange-vertical"></i></div> 
                     <select class="form-control" name="txtRelation[]">
                     <?php 
                       $list_rl = DB::table('relationship')->select('id','Name')->get();
                     ?>
                     @foreach($list_rl as $item_rl)
                       <option value="{!! $item_rl->id !!}">{!! $item_rl->Name !!}</option>
                     @endforeach 
                     </select>
                    <div class="input-group-addon"><button><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button></div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Người đi</label>
                   <div class="input-group">
                   <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-people"></i></div> 
                     <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="txtGuest[]"></textarea>                          
                    <div class="input-group-addon"><button><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button></div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="exampleInputpwd1">chặng bay</label>
                   <div class="input-group">
                   <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-fighter-jet"></i></div>
                     <select class="form-control" name="txtFlies[]">
                     <?php 
                       $list_cb = DB::table('return')->select('id','CodeFN')->get();
                     ?>
                     @foreach($list_cb as $item_cb)
                       <option value="{!! $item_cb->id !!}">{!! $item_cb->CodeFN !!}</option>
                     @endforeach
                     </select>
                     <div class="input-group-addon"><button><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button></div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="exampleInputpwd2">mức giảm</label>
                   <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="ti-package"></i></div>
                     <select class="form-control" name="txtDiscount[]">
                     <?php 
                       $list_dc = DB::table('discounts')->select('id','CodeDist')->get();
                     ?>
                     @foreach($list_dc as $item_dc)
                       <option value="{!! $item_dc->id !!}">{!! $item_dc->CodeDist !!}</option>
                     @endforeach
                     </select>
                    <div class="input-group-addon"><button><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button></div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <div class="checkbox checkbox-success"> </div>                         
                 </div>
                 <div class="text-right">
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light m-r-10">Thêm mới</button>                       
               </div>
             </form>
   ```
2. my controller

$input = Input::all();
         $count = count($input['txtnguoixin']);

```
     $ticketin = array();
        for($i=1; $i<$count; $i++){
           if($input['txtnguoixin'][$i]){
             array_push($ticketin, array(      
            'NoCV'        => $input['txtSCV'][$i],
            'nguoixin'    => $input['txtnguoixin'][$i],
            'Com_id'      => $input['txtCom'][$i],
            'Room_id'     => $input['txtRoom'][$i],
            'Reason_id'   => $input['txtlido'][$i],
            'Nguoidi'     => $input['txtGuest'][$i],
            'Relation_id' => $input['txtRelation'][$i],
            'return_id'   => $input['txtFlies'][$i],
            'discount_id' => $input['txtDiscount'][$i],
            'leader_id'   => $input['txtleader'][$i],
            'nguoinhap'   => 'muoi',
            'assignto'    => $input['txtReceiver'][$i],
            'tinhtrang'   => 1


             ));
           }
        }

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($ticketin);
        echo "</pre>";
```

But it has erro undefined offset 1.

Comment: Try to dump the $input variable to inspect it's content, and maybe even paste the output here

Comment: I had var_dump ($input) but have error   ErrorException in testcontroller.php line 32:
Undefined offset: 1

Comment: dump it like this dd($input); or var_dump($input);exit; right after defining the $input variable

Comment: Hi, this is my idea. I have input type and then the user want add more input to insert database. but when I insert, just only 1 row into db, row 2 do not. Do you have solutions?

Comment: To be honest I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve here. So for example why are you using the array syntax on inputs? Are you adding fields dynamically? Take this for example: "txtleader[]", why not "txtleader"?

Comment: yes. I want to add fields dynamically

Comment: Still having the problem? Maybe it would be a better solution to move this conversion in chat

Comment: I Have only 1 reputation, not yet enough to chat. I can chat with you on facebook ?